# An argument named "vpc_security_group_ids" is not expected here ... not sure why i am getting this error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

My terraform security local ec2 module looks like so

```
resource "aws_instance" "mysql" {
  ami           = data.aws_ami.latest_amazon_linux.id
  instance_type = var.instance_type                # override this at module call
  key_name = aws_key_pair.my_local_pubkey.key_name # override this at module call
  vpc_security_group_ids = [var.default_sg]        # override security group at module call

}
```

and when i reference it in main.tf to override the `vpc_security_group_ids` like so

```
module "ec2" {
  source                 = "./modules/ec2"
  instance_type          = "t2.medium"
  vpc_security_group_ids = [module.security_group.sg_id]
}
```

I get an error saying `vpc_security_group_ids` not expected here.

Answer (score 2):

There are at least two issues with the current code:

1. the variable name you defined in the module is not provided a value with the module call, i.e., that is why terraform is telling you that it is not expecting an argument called `vpc_security_group_ids`, since the argument name is actually `default_sg`
2. you have probably defined the `default_sg` variable as a string, and you are trying to pass a list. This is how you are passing the `default_sg` to `vpc_security_group_ids`: `vpc_security_group_ids = [var.default_sg]`. And in the module call you are using `vpc_security_group_ids = [module.security_group.sg_id]`, which means the value passed to whatever is the module argument will already be a list.

To fix these issues, you need the following:

```
module "ec2" {
  source        = "./modules/ec2"
  instance_type = "t2.medium"
  default_sg    = module.security_group.sg_id
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are creating Instances in a VPC, you will use `vpc_security_group_ids`.
if you are using default VPC, then the entry should be just `security_groups`.
so that line should be
`security_groups = [var.default_sg]` in the resource and `security_groups = [module.security_group.sg_id]` in the module.